# How can I protect my self from someone querying my GAE application on a loop and racking up a huge bill for me?

Tags: google-app-engine

I have just enabled billing in my Google App Engine and I was wondering how to stop someone querying my app on a loop for a day and racking up a huge bill that I would have to pay Google? Is there an option to prevent this on GAE console? is not then is there any code i can add to my application to prevent this?

Answer (score 2):

Currently, all you can really do is manually blacklist up to 100 IP addresses in your `dos.yaml` file.  However, this requires that you keep a lookout on the traffic to your app somehow.  You could also limit the maximum number of instances that allowed to run, but this kind of defeats the purpose of an auto-scaling platform like AppEngine.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/dos